# xDB Data Migration tool and vanila Sitecore instance

Tags: xdb, xconnect, mongodb, data-exchange-framework, migration

Is it possible to migrate xDB data from existing Sitecore 8.2 to a fresh Sitecore 9.x instance using the xDB Data Migration tool? I mean if I install a fresh Sitecore 9.x instance (not upgraded one), can I migrate the analytics data from 8.2 via the migration too having only the Mongo Collection database, or it requires some other data from existing solution (e.g. some data from Master and so on)?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible.

The only one thing I see in the xDB Data Migration tool where some data from Master are needed. It's a profile data. To migrate profile score facet properly you need to have all these items under `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Profiles`.

Comment: Vlad, thanks. One more thing: is this data optional? if this data is missing, the migration process will skip appropriate entities? or this data must be, to successfully complete migration?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it should be skipped.